# How to copy data from flat file into multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have relational database with tables:Customer, Region, Time, Fact.
[image] 
There are 21 flat files. Each flat file has 4 columns. 
[image]

All files are 1.5GB. How to import flat files into SQL SERVER tables using SSIS(Integration Services)?

```
column1(flat file)->CustomerID(Customer table) 
column2(flat file)->AntennaID1(Region table) 
column3(flat file)->AntennaID2(Region table) 
column4(flat file)->Dividing into parts->Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [import Wizard in SSMS (David Chapelle's Blog)](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/Importing-And-Exporting-Data-With-Sql-Server-2012.htm) and it will generate a SISS package for you if you choose to save it.

Import the whole file into one table, and the use SQL to break it up in to multiple tables (normalisation)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be Import your data using Import/Export wizard into a staging Table, Once you have all the data in Sql server then Inert Data into destination tables. using Insert statements. Safer and less error prone way of doing such operations.

Comment: sir, i have tries this but it is very slow. I waited for 1.5 hour for one file and gave up.

Comment: It is the safest and simplest way to achieve this, If your files are large in size dont worry about the amount of time it takes, You will be doing a clean less error prone operation, which can save you hours of maintenance work if you are trying to import directly into destination tables and some error occurs :)